# How can create a vector of Point Cloud as Buffer

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, c++14, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

What the efficient way to create a vector of **point clouds** used as a buffer in order to store multi-scanning point clouds

Comment: I posted an answer that I think is what you need. If not please post some code and I will adapt the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting C++11, you can use `std::vector` as an RAII buffer.
Instead of allocating the space yourself using `new` and then having to `delete` the pointer to avoid memory leaks, you can simply create an `std::vector` and pre-allocate it so that it can be used a a buffer:
(some of this is some pseudo code since I'm not familiar with point clouds)

```
#include <vector>

constexpr unsigned int numberOfPoints = 100;
std::vector<point_clouds> buffer(numberOfPoints);
scan_point_clound_func(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
point_cloud p = buffer[0];
```

Comment: Thank you  :) ZivS

Comment: If this answers the question, Tick the v sign next to it to acknowledge a correct solution